# JScript -- Unity transform.eulerAngles.y not Working

Tags: unity-game-engine, jscript

So last week I started working on an RPG and I've started working on the enemy AI and it should rotate to it's target but it doesn't. What I did is for the enemy I created a child object and put a script that rotates it to the target, then in the enemy script I did this:

```
if(transform.eulerAngles.y > rotTracker.transform.eulerAngles.y) {

    transform.eulerAngles.y -= 2 * Time.deltaTime;
}
if(transform.eulerAngles.y < rotTracker.transform.eulerAngles.y) {

    transform.eulerAngles.y += 2 * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

the rotTracker is a GameObject variable. So, what is wrong with this code? The rotation tracker changes rotations but not the enemy. Maybe because it has child objects that look at a different thing? I created a sprite and put it on top of the enemy and it represents the enemies health and always turns towards the camera.

Comment: dude ... "unityscript" ***is deprecated from Unity - you can not use it***. You are utterly 100% wasting your time dude.  It is an absolute, total, complete waste of your time.  Note that c# is *actually much easier to use*, you'll have to change over your learning now

Comment: I plan on switching to C# but JS is not that bad actually. It works fine with a few bugs here and there but other than that it's really good. Anyways, Joe, are you the guy that created The Witness ? Cuz you know Jonathan Blow, Joe Blow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change directly the angles. You need to change the vector positions. For example:

```
var yRotation -= 2 * Time.deltaTime;    
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, yRotation, 0);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm just I did it like this: transform.eulerAngles += Vector3(0, 1, 0) * number * Time.deltaTime;

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `transform.eulerAngles` for increment, only fixed values. Also, better set it as vector, not the single axis.

If you've put the the script on the child and actually want to rotate the parent, then you have the wrong transform, but I can't clearly read that.

Further on I'd recommend doing something like this:

```
var dir = transform.postion - target.position;
dir.y = 0;    // set the axis you want to rotate around to 0
var targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

`speed` being a factor for how fast you want to rotate.
(I think the code should be correct, I'm using C# though.)

Comment: This is a good way to do it to but It's not what I actually want because I want only one axis

Comment: You can do that too this way, did an edit, should be correct I think.

Comment: Yea this looks okay now but I don't know why but I don't like Quaternions. Anyways I would use this :)